Is the term "AUROC curve" actually correct or meaningful?
When I got into Machine Learning over 15 years ago, I learned that AUC stands for "Area Under the Curve", meaning "area under the ROC curve" and ROC being the "Receiver Operating Characteristic".
Now I'm supervising students myself and (of course) they sometimes use different terms depending on what literature and sources they read first. I heard of AUROC, which according to some opinions here is a better term than AUC, since the latter doesn't specify which curve is meant and others than ROC are possible.
But then I read AUROC curve and it just sounds wrong to me on many levels. (I'm not a native English speaker.)
Either you mean the area under the curve, which would be AUC or AUROC, or the curve itself, which is the ROC curve, so AUROC curve doesn't really make sense to me. However, searching through CV here I've found that it is used a few times and never corrected or addressed, e.g. in

Why are ROC curves and AUC values not always relevant?
How to interpret the AUROC curve for mortgage denial/approval?
How to Interpret AUROC score?

So, my question is: Am I correct or overly pedantic here? Or am missing something obvious?
Clarification:
It seems my question was ambiguous and I should clarify:
My problem is with using the term "AUROC curve" designating the curve, not the value, like

For a random classifier, the AUROC curve would be a diagonal from [0,0] to [1,1]


If you read AUROC curve as "Area Under the Receiver Operating Characteristic curve", or "Area Under the ROC curve" it is actually not weird at all. There is no redundancy; the C stands for Characteristic, not curve... Now, if someone said "AUROCC curve", or "area under the AUROC curve", there would be a problem. But I have never seen/heard any of this... AUROC curve sounds perfectly fine to me.

To give a source, the 1st paper I know is from 1954 - Peterson W, Birdsall T, Fox W. The theory of signal detectability. Transactions of the IRE Professional Group on Information Theory. 1954 Sep;4(4):171–212.
Early in the paper it says "Associated with each such operating level are conditional probabilities that the answer is a false alarm and the conditional probability of detection. Graphs of these quantities, called receiver operating characteristic, or ROC, curves are convenient for evaluating a receiver."
So in early usage ROC is not a curve, but a characteristic of a receiver!

@astaines, thanks for the link. Here is a link to a post on CV which goes a bit deeper into the origin of the terminology https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341043/what-is-the-origin-of-the-receiver-operating-characteristic-roc-terminology Basically radar (receiver) operators discriminating between friendly or ennemy airplanes, and optimizing the false negatives vs. false positives trade-off.

My bad, I wasn't specific enough: "AUROC curve" was used to refer to the curve, not the value. I do know that the C in ROC stands for characteristic, not curve, but then AUROC curve = "area under the ROC curve", which is the area, not the curve ;)

@Sentry, ahhh. It would have helped to quote some actual sentences in your question, to distinguish between mentionning the actual value of the AUROC curve, as opposed to the curve itself (which indeed should be ROC curve).

I think this is just a quirk of English usage, where the exact meaning of a word or acronym gets "lost" and part of it is repeated. I don't think it has anything to do with statistics really. And, while I won't say you're being overly pedantic (I'm often accused of being pedantic), I don't think this is an issue that has to worry you.

it's like when project managers say "Kanban board" :) Kanban is a board in Japanese, silly but not worth fighting for

Sometimes it becomes so common .... Sherwood Forest (wood means forest).  Greenwich Village (wich means village).

And the river Avon in the U.K. means "river river" and Bredon Hill, which is "hill hill hill"  This seems to happen more than you might think! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tautological_place_names

We've all used an ATM machine at 8am in the morning, right?

@Dave and entered our PIN number?

@DikranMarsupial You mean your personal PIN number?
